# Forge dataviz reference app and multiple models (aggregated view?)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I´m building a PoC app based on the Forge Dataviz reference application and have got a custom application to work alright with one ifc-file. My next challenge is that I want to be able to load multiple models into the application. I have found this https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/loading-multiple-models-forge-viewer-v7
but I don´t really know where to start (fairly new to web development and React). I have built my current PoC app on the Navisworks example from the Dataviz reference app.
Is there anybody that could help me by coding an example of using multiple models with Dataviz?
Cheers!
//Henrik

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to web development this is going to be challenging, but not to worry we have the resources. Start with [Learnforge](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/?id=learn-autodesk-forge) finish the first tutorial [view your models](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewmodels). Understand the code spend a few days only on tutorials and learning javascript and basic nodejs functionality, then jump into Forge documentation and blogs and start tinkering with example codes. Dataviz is advanced, but still easy to use, but to understand it you need to be good in web development first.